# Manage python packages in Sublime text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3, package, sublimerepl

Working with Ubuntu 14.04

How to tell Sublime text 3 and SublimeREPL where to look for the python packages?

From my terminal, `pip list` returns a list with many python packages like that:

```
numexpr (2.2.2)
numpy (1.8.2)
oauthlib (0.6.1)
oneconf (0.3.7)
openpyxl (2.2.5)
PAM (0.4.2)
pandas (0.16.2)
```

However, inside Sublime text 3, on the console:

```
>>> import openpyxl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'openpyxl'

>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pandas'

>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

From the SulbimeREPL console:

```
Python 3.3.6 (default, Jan 28 2015, 17:27:09) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pandas'
>>> import openpyxl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

So, I assume that something needs to be set up.

Comment: What is the output of `import sys; sys.executable` ?

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv? If so, what's the path to its executable?

Comment: @ Railslide no I am not using virtualenv, I am using Ubuntu on virtualBox. @ Anand, the output in the sublime text 3 console is: `python3`  and the output on the SublimeREPL console is: `/usr/bin/python3.3`

Comment: What's the output of `pip --version`?

Comment: @Railslide, output from pip --version gives me in my terminal: `pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to point SublimeRepl to the right interpreter.

Add to `Settings -> Package Settings -> SublimeREPL -> Settings - User`

```
{
    "default_extend_env": {"PATH": "{PATH}:/usr/lib/python2.7"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
python3 -m pip install --user openpyxl
```