# How to install pandas for sublimetext?

Tags: python, pandas, sublimetext3

I cannot find the way to install pandas for sublimetext. Do you might know how?

There is something called pandas theme in the package control, but that was not the one I needed; I need the pandas for python for sublimetext.

Comment: There is no special installation for Sublime Text or any editor. Just install the package as you would normally do using `pip` and then configure Sublime Text to run Python scripts. You might want to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400372/manage-python-packages-in-sublime-text-3#31450170).

Answer (score 0):

For me, "pip install pandas" was not working, so I used pip3 install pandas which worked nicely.

I would advise using either pip install pandas or pip3 install pandas for sublime text

Comment: Be careful with the env's

Answer (score -1):

You can install this awesome theme through the Package Control.

1. Press cmd/ctrl + shift + p to open the command palette.
2. Type “install package” and press enter. Then search for “Panda Syntax Sublime”

**Manual installation**

1. Download the latest release, extract and rename the directory to “Panda Syntax”.
2. Move the directory inside your sublime Packages directory. (Preferences > Browse packages…)

**Activate the theme**

Open you preferences (Preferences > Setting - User) and add this lines:

"color_scheme": "Packages/Panda Syntax Sublime/Panda/panda-syntax.tmTheme"
NOTE: Restart Sublime Text after activating the theme.

Comment: But, a theme, is that pandas or is it a theme? I do not understand the difference or what a theme might be. It is very confusing on their site because I only see that they use another font.